# Tag merge and synonym or blackhole - Cisco-asa & ASA

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The ASA tag has 109 Qs, the Cisco-ASA tag only has 79.
Please merge ASA into the more formal Cisco-ASA.

Comment: +1. I just went on meta for this exact purpose !

Answer (score 3):

completed; thanks for the suggestion!